# Is there a system for PC reputation in D&D 3.5

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, game-recommendation, homebrew

I'm looking for an optional, 3rd party or well defined homebrew reputation for 3.5. I want to be able to track the impact of my player characters interactions with the environment, their access to important people etc as they level up and do things in the world. I want it to track:

1. Character overall reputation
2. Character Reputation with specific settlements (Obviously if they have visited and helped a town their reputation would be different there than another town where they are just known)
3. Not exactly Karma but something like a Good compared to Evil tracker.

These things should be tracked in a way that's easy for me to maintain.

Comment: *Unearthed Arcana* has a [Reputation](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/campaigns/reputation.htm) system, but I have never used it.

Comment: @KRyan This looks to be in the direction I am aiming. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With credit to @KRyan for mentioning it first, Unearthed Arcana does feature a system that addresses most of your needs. It was released under the OGL and is available from the Hypertext d20 SRD [here](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/campaigns/reputation.htm)

In brief, here is how it interacts with each of your needs.

1. Character's have an overall reputation score. When encountering an NPC, a DC25 d20 roll + Reputation + NPC's int modifier determines if the reputation applies. If so, the reputation modifies certain social skills (Bluff, Diplomacy, etc.) either up or down.
2. The system as written does not support this. Reputation has a sort of radius of effect based on class level, with most other adjudications left in the hands of the GM. It would be a simple modification (albeit requiring significantly more bookkeeping) to track this separately to whatever level of geographical detail one chooses.
3. This is handled as Fame vs. Infamy. A reputation could be either and affects different groups accordingly. An infamous assassin can expect good treatment at the Thieves Guild and significantly less good treatment at the Church of Lathlander for example. Again, this is generally left to common sense and DM fiat.

Answer (score 0):

There is a prestige class (Forgotten Realms) called Shadow Thief of Amn/Guild Thief that gives Reputation as a class feature. Effectively, it adds a +1 bonus to your Leadership score. Just throwing that out there.